# How to prevent script execution after BootstrapDialog opens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-dialog

I am using BootstrapDialog for showing some alerts.

```
    BootstrapDialog.alert({
          type:  BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
          title: 'Oops! ',
          message: 'Error, occured',
          buttons: [{
              label: 'Ok'

          }]
      });
    window.location.replace("http://example.com");
```

I want that if dialog opens it doesn't redirect to another page. It should only redirect if a user clicks "OK" button, as if I were using alert in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should attach the `window.location` code inside the `buttons` attribute. Try doing this:

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
    type:  BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
    title: 'Oops! ',
    message: 'Error, occured',
    buttons: [{
        label: 'Ok',
        action: function(dialog) {
            window.location.replace("http://example.com");
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: The function is not executing. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Oh! I realized an error, it should be BootstrapDialog.show()

Comment: @CodeFather welcome! If the answer did help please upvote or mark as correct to help future visitors. Otherwise, please post the correct answer you found and mark it as the correct one :)